# How to create buttons as pictures in swift?

Tags: swift, image, button

Can someone point me into the rite direction on how to select different parts in a picture in swift  ?

For example if i had a picture of a body and i want to select the head ?

Thank you ,

Answer (score 0):

You could put the image as background, then clear buttons (no text, no image) on top?

If all images follow the same type I think this can work. Make a view to contain the image(s), fill up the mentioned view with it and put the buttons over the image (inside the view). Play with constraints a bit until the buttons match nicely over the parts you want.